# How to get the exact number of rows in webtable using xpath in webdriver 2 using C#

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Want to fetch the number of rows present in the table *Xpath* I am passing is `.//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_Tabs_TabPanelEmploymentAdmin_EmploymentAdmin_grvAssignmentHistory']`

My Page HTML is like

```
<table id="ctl00_mainContent_Tabs_TabPanelEmploymentAdmin_EmploymentAdmin_grvAssignmentHistory"
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

my code is returning 0 as out put.

```
IWebElement TargetElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathVal));
IList<IWebElement> ElementCollectionHead = TargetElement.FindElements(By.XPath(xPathVal+"/tbody/tr[*]"));        
int RowCount = ElementCollectionHead.Count;
```

Comment: If `FindElements()` is returning zero rows, the most likely answer is your table is contained within one or `iframe` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously i was using

```
IWebElement TargetElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathVal));
IList<IWebElement> ElementCollectionHead = TargetElement.FindElements(By.XPath(xPathVal+"/tbody/tr[*]"));        
int RowCount = ElementCollectionHead.Count;
```

The problem was in 2nd line.It should be like:

```
IList<IWebElement> ElementCollectionHead = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(xPathVal + "/tbody/tr[*]"));
```

Dont know why 1st was not working.If some one can then i will be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons of this issue can be as follows:

1. Selenium needs some time to identify the element(element load time)
2. The elements are inside the `iframe` as mentioned by @Richard.

The solution of first problem is probably to use Explicit wait with the `FindElement()`
(Just as a side note, I would prefer `CssSelector` over `XPath` here since I do not have to use XPath)

```
By css = By.CssSelector("#ctl00_mainContent_Tabs_TabPanelEmploymentAdmin_EmploymentAdmin_grvAssignmentHistory tr");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IList<IWebElement> elementCollectionHead = wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.FindElements(css));
int rowCount = elementCollectionHead.Count;
```

If the issue is an `iframe` then you have to use `SwitchTo()` in order to switch to the `iframe` and then look for elements

```
// you can use xpath or cssselector to identify the iframe
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("iframe id")));

By css = By.CssSelector("#ctl00_mainContent_Tabs_TabPanelEmploymentAdmin_EmploymentAdmin_grvAssignmentHistory tr");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

IList<IWebElement> elementCollectionHead = wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.FindElements(css));
int rowCount = elementCollectionHead.Count;

driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time .but there no iframe preset and page got enough time to load as it was validating other labels and links before the row count.
here is the absolute xpath for 2nd row  to provide you the branching details.

Absulatepath: /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]

Relative Path: .//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_Tabs_TabPanelEmploymentAdmin_EmploymentAdmin_grvAssignmentHistory']/tbody/tr[2]

Comment: Does the absolute xpath pass?

Comment: @Arnab Have you tried the solution I provided? And, did not that work?

Comment: many many thanks for your help and support.For my case the 2nd one is not applicable.i tried the 1st soln also and its not work .Please find my below comment.I change my code little and its worked.please dont ask me the reason as i am very new in selenium.

Comment: Interesting. I wish I had the access to the actual website so I could figure out why it did not work. BTW, thanks